# Encoding BufferedWriter Fix Sonar

Tags: java

pasa que estoy intentando indicar el encoding en un BuferedWriter, pero no logro hacerlo, mi implementación :
Sonar findBug : **Reliance on default encoding**

```
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(comunConstants.getRutaArchivo(),true));
```

Leí que con Charset, pero obtengo error en sintaxis.

```
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(comunConstants.getRutaArchivoRegistro(),true),Charset.defaultCharset());
```

¿que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví con :
There's no reason you can't construct your BufferedWriter on top of the OutputStreamWriter though.

```
String path=comunConstants.getRutaArchivoRegistro();
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter
            (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path),"UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Cuando puedas (usualmente unas horas despues) puedes marcar tu respuesta como **respuesta aceptada** para que sea mas util a otros usuarios